# Access jQuery Object from inside a custom binding handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to access a jQuery Object, which happens to be an input text box to do some validations and adding date picker but unfortunately I am unable to do so.

I am working with KnockoutJS.

I wanted to access the 'input' and call datepicker() on it if 'Datatype' happens to be a 'Date' or a 'Datetime'. But whenever I try to search using `.closest('td').next('td').html()`, I get a null (from inside the custom bind). Trying this so that I can call the datetimepicker constructor on the input based on the datatype 'td'.

Below is the fiddle that I am trying to work with

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/nkkt88v2/2/

```
   var format = function (str, col) {
    col = typeof col === 'object' ? col : Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return str.replace(/\{\{|\}\}|\{(\w+)\}/g, function (m, n) {
        if (m == "{{") {
            return "{";
        }
        if (m == "}}") {
            return "}";
        }
        return col[n];
    });
};

var data = ko.observableArray([{
    paramKey: ko.observable('keyName'),
    paramValue: ko.observable('Test1'),
    dataType: ko.observable('Date')
}]);


var ParamConstr = function (key, value, dataType) {
    return {
        ParamKey: ko.observable(key),
        ParamValue: ko.observable(value),
        DataType: ko.observable(dataType)

    };
};
var my = my || {};
function Generator() { };

Generator.prototype.rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + Date.now();

Generator.prototype.getId = function () {
    return this.rand++;
};
var idGen = new Generator();
//var ParamData = ko.observableArray([]);
my.viewModel = {
    ParamData : ko.observableArray([]),
    addParam: function () {
         this.ParamData.push(new ParamConstr("$$" + "key1", "value1","Date"));
    }};

ko.bindingHandlers.hidden = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, function () { return !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); });
    }
};


ko.bindingHandlers.clickToEdit = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            link = document.createElement("a"),
            input = document.createElement("input");

        var id = idGen.getId();
        input.setAttribute("id", id);

        element.appendChild(link);
        element.appendChild(input);


        console.log(document.getElementById(id).id);

        var dataType = $(format("#{0}", id)).parent().next('td').html();
        //.parent().next().html();
        //.closest('td').next('td').html().toString();
        console.log(dataType);

        switch ($(format("#{0}", id)).parent().next('td').html()) {

            case "Datetime":
                $(format("#{0}", id)).datetimepicker();
                break;

            case "Date":
                $(format("#{0}", id)).datetimepicker({
                    timepicker: false,
                    format: 'Y/m/d'
                });
                break;
        }

        observable.editing = ko.observable(false);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(link, {
            text: observable,
            hidden: observable.editing,
            click: observable.editing.bind(null, true)
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, {
            value: observable,
            visible: observable.editing,
            hasfocus: observable.editing,
            event: {
                keyup: function (data, event) {
                    //if user hits enter, set editing to false, which makes field lose focus
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                        input.blur();
                        observable.editing(false);
                        return false;
                    }
                    //if user hits escape, push the current observable value back to the field, then set editing to false
                    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                        observable.valueHasMutated();
                        observable.editing(false);
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

html:

```
<div>
    <button id="InputSubmitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" data-bind="click: addParam"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;Add</button>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Data type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ParamData">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: ParamKey" style="width: 20%"></td>
            <td data-bind="clickToEdit: ParamValue" data-text="" style="width: 20%"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: DataType" style="width: 20%"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help as to how I can fix this would be great!

Comment: If your goal is to get the data-type then you can use allbindingaccessors parameter to achieve it. 

Modify your html to 

 <td data-bind="clickToEdit: ParamValue, datatype:DataType" data-text="" style="width: 20%"></td> and in your custom binding 
Adding the below lines gives you the datatype
var dataType = allBindingsAccessor().datatype();
        console.log(allBindingsAccessor().datatype());. You can use this as an input to switch case to compare against the required datatype. Check it and let us know if it worked

Comment: That did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you got an answer from G_S.

If anyone is wondering what was the right selector, `var dataType = $(element).next().text();` does the job perfectly. You couldn't access any data because at the time of the call, it wasn't there yet. You could try `var dataType = $(element).prev().text();` and see that you can retrieve $$key1.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/nkkt88v2/2/)

Anyway, as you got answered, I didn't dig further on how to resolve this, have a good day :)